# UIManager Changes color only once (Nimbus)

Tags: java, swing, colors, nimbus, uimanager

Refer to this bug:

[4848910 : UIManager only updates colors once](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4848910)

I have two buttons on a JFrame. From first button I am changing LAF Color by

```
UIManager.put( "Button.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.red) );
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( this.getContentPane() );
```

and on second button I am changing LAF color with

```
UIManager.put( "Button.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.green) );
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI( this.getContentPane() );
```

Here I am using ColorUIResource (as described by the resolution of the bug)  but my problem remains the same as described in the refered bug. i.e. UIManager changes the color when any of the button gets clicked for the very first time but doesnt changes the color on subsequent clicks.

Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

- not possible to change that direct way
- is possible that with reseting the current Nimbus Color scheme (`UIManager.getLookAndFeel().uninitialize();`)
- [another (similair) issue is in my question about Nimbus & Font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958004/change-font-at-runtime)

code

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIDefaults;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class NimbusTestButtonsBackground extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private javax.swing.JButton button;

    public NimbusTestButtonsBackground() {
        button = new javax.swing.JButton();
        button.setText("Text");
        add(button);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            private Random r = new Random();

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Color c = new Color(r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256), r.nextInt(256));
                try {
                    LookAndFeel lnf = UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getClass().newInstance();
                    UIDefaults uiDefaults = lnf.getDefaults();
                    uiDefaults.put("nimbusBase", c);
                    UIManager.getLookAndFeel().uninitialize();
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnf);
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                UIDefaults defaults = UIManager.getDefaults();
                defaults.put("Button.background", c);
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(button);
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new NimbusTestButtonsBackground().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```